# How do I preserve certain words from stopword and wildcard removal in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a large input file as:

```
d0 NoS19
s0 This movie has been regarded as the cream of Hong Kong gangster and copmovie.
s1 And has won 22 awards.
s2 But we all know awards don't mean a thing sometimes.
```

I want to remove wildcards, stopwords and then stem the input. This is working fine for me. My problem is how to preserve the identifiers such as d0, NoS19, s0, s1, s2 etc from the wildcard, stem and stopword removal.

I make use of porter stemmer, and have a file with an extensive list of stopwords,

For my wilcard removal, this is what I did:

```
$reviewContent =~ tr/A-Z/a-z/; #transfer upper case to lower case

$reviewContent =~ s/[a-z_0-9\.]*\@[a-z_0-9\.]*/ /g; 
$reviewContent =~ s/[^a-zA-Z\']/ /g; 
$reviewContent =~ s/ +\'/ /g; 
$reviewContent =~ s/\' +/ /g;
$reviewContent  =~ s/[^\w.-]/ /g; 
$reviewContent =~ s/[ ]+/ /g; 
$reviewContent =~ s/^\s+//g;
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: yeah TLP there is a perl algorithm for stemming. It is called porter.pm

Comment: You should link to documentation, for example at metacpan.org, and perhaps mention that you are talking about a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, split each line into the code and comment first, then operate on the comment only:

```
my ($code, $comment) = split ' ', $reviewContent, 2;
if ($code !~ /^d/) {         # I asume the header always starts with a "d".
    $comment =~ s/[a-z_0-9\.]*\@[a-z_0-9\.]*/ /g;
    $comment =~ s/[^a-zA-Z\']/ /g;
    $comment =~ s/ +\'/ /g;
    $comment =~ s/\' +/ /g;
    $comment =~ s/[^\w.-]/ /g;
    $comment =~ s/[ ]+/ /g;
    $comment =~ s/^\s+//g;
}
print "$code $comment\n";
```

Comment: Great. Yeah you are right. The code is 100%. Thanks @choroba!!!!!!!!!. You saved my day!!